# Explanation of the getView() method of an ArrayAdapter

Tags: java, android, android-listview, android-arrayadapter, android-adapter

Could you explain the `getView()` method of an `ArrayAdapter`.

I read the docs and it has three parameters:

- `position`: The position of the item within the adapter's data set of
  the item whose view we want.
- `convertView`: The old view to reuse, if possible. Note: You should check that this view is non-null and of an  appropriate type before using. If it is not possible to convert this view to display the correct data, this method can create a new view.
  Heterogeneous lists can specify their number of view types, so that this View is always of the right type (see getViewTypeCount() and getItemViewType(int)).
- `parent`: The parent that this view will eventually be attached to

I understood the `position` parameter. Like they said, it's imply the position of the item, who view has been requested.

Where does `convertView` come from. I've seen many examples where they check if `convertView` is null. If is is null, they inflate a new instance of the row layout, populate it and return it. I guess I've gotten my head around that too but one thing still baffles me. What is the layout that is passed in through the `convertView` parameter. Is if [the `resource` parameter that is passed in when initialising the `ArrayAdapter`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html#ArrayAdapter%28android.content.Context,%20int,%20int%29)? Is is a cached copy of the last layout returned by `getView()`?

And lastly. What does the `parent` parameter do. I haven't seen too many examples utilising this. Most of them simply reuse/inflate a row layout and return it.

(I'm asking because I have an on-click animation in my `ListView`. Specifically [this one that aims to replicate Spotify's dropdown quick action menu](http://udinic.wordpress.com/2011/09/03/expanding-listview-items/). My animation has been a little sluggish. After diagnosing this issue for a while, I've realized that this has been due to the fact that my `getView()` method takes a bit of time to complete as I'm inflating a fresh row layout in every iteration. Someone suggested caching the row layout in a `ViewHolder` while other examples point to reusing the `convertView` parameter i.e. only inflating a row layout if `convertView` is null.)

Answer (score 44, accepted):

> Is is a cached copy of the last layout returned by getView()?

The `convertView` is the view of a row that left the screen(so it isn't the last view returned by the `getView` method). For example, the list is first shown, in this case `convertView` is `null`, no row view was previously built and left the screen. If you scroll down, row 0 will leave the screen(will not be visible anymore), when that happens the `ListView` may choose to keep that view in a cache to later use it(this makes sense, as the rows of a `ListView` generally have the same layout with only the data being different). The reason to keep some views in a cache and later use them is because the `getView` method could be called a lot of times(each time the user scrolls up/down and new rows appear on the screen). If each time the row view would need to be recreated this would have resulted in a lot of objects being created which is something to avoid. In your `getView` method you would check `convertView` to see if it is `null`. If it's `null` then you **must** build a new row view and populate it with data, if it isn't `null`, the `ListView` has offered you a previous view. Having this previous view means you don't need to build a new row layout, instead you **must** populate it with the correct data, as that cached view has the old data still attached to it(you would see a lot of questions on stackoverflow where users ask why the rows of their `ListView` are duplicating when they scroll down).

> What does the parent parameter do. I haven't seen too many examples
>   utilising this. Most of them simply reuse/inflate a row layout and
>   return it.

It should be used to get the correct `LayoutParams` for the newly inflated/built row. For example, if you inflate a layout which has a `RelativeLayout` as the root and you don't use the `parent` to get the `LayoutParams` you could have some problems with the row layout. To take the parent in consideration you would use :

```
convertView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.row_layout, parent, false);
```

Answer (score 2):

My understanding of `convertView` is that it's essentially views that have been recycled because they're not being used at the moment - for example, you scroll down the list, the ones at the top aren't on the screen, so they get passed into this parameter for use when you need a new view (so you don't have to create a whole new one while having unused ones sitting around idle). iOS has a similar method called `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier`. If each row of your listview has the same structure, it's safe to cast this to the appropriate type and just update the information in it - text, images, etc. It will be a View that was previously returned by a `getView()` call for the same list.

My best guess (and it is admittedly a guess) with `parent` is that it's the view that this adapter's list is a child of. It gives you a route back to the rendering system if you need a context, access to the resource system, to pass information to or receive information from the list's parent view.