# Is there a way to add two textviews to arrayadapter

Tags: android, android-adapter

I want to use two `textviews` side by side in my `listview` and also want to perform search on them. Is there any way to do this without creating any new class? Here is what I have done so far:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
final String[] elename ={"Hydrogen","Helium","Lithium","Beryllium","Boron","Carbon","Nitrogen","Oxygen","Fluorine","Neon","Sodium","Magnesium","Aluminium","Silicon","Phosphorous","Sulphur","Chlorine","Argon","Potassium","Calcium","Scandium","Titanium","Vanadium","Chromium","Manganese","Iron","Cobalt","Nickel","Copper","Zinc","Gallium","Germanium","Arsenic","Selenium","Bromine","Krypton","Rubidium","Strontium","Yttrium","Zirconium","Niobium","Molybdenum","Technetium","Ruthenium","Rhodium","Palladium","Silver","Cadmium","Indium","Tin","Antimony","Tellurium","Iodine","Xenon","Caesium","Barium","Lanthanum","Cerium","Praseodymium","Neodymium","Promethium","Samarium","Europium","gadoliium","Terbium","Dysprosium","Holmium","Erbium","Thulium","Ytterbium","Lutetium","Hafnium","Tantalum","Tungsten","Rhenium","Osmium","Iridium","Platinum","Gold","Mercury","Thallium","Lead","Bismuth","Polonium","Astatine","Radon","Francium","Radium","Actinium","Thorium","Protactinium","Uranium","Neptunium","Plutonium","Americium","Curium","Berkelium","Californium","Einsteinium","Fermium","Mendelevium","Nobelium","Lawrencium","Rutherfordium","Dubnium","Seaborgium","Bohrium","Hassium","Meitnerium","Darmstadtium","Roentgenium","Copernicium","Ununtrium","Ununquadium","Ununpentium","Ununhexium","Ununseptium","Ununoctium"};
final String[] nos = {"1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","10","11","12","13","14","15","16","17","18","19","20","21","22","23","24","25","26","27","28","29","30","31","32","33","34","35","36","37","38","39","40","41","42","43","44","45","46","47","48","49","50","51","52","53","54","55","56","57","58","59","60","61","62","63","64","65","66","67","68","69","70","71","72","73","74","75","76","77","78","79","80","81","82","83","84","85","86","87","88","89","90","91","92","93","94","95","96","97","98","99","100","101","102","103","104","105","106","107","108","109","110","111","112","113","114","115","116","117","118"};

ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.list_item,R.id.element_name, elename);
    final EditText searchBar = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.searchbar);
    final DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout)findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    final ListView navList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.left_drawer);
    final LinearLayout linearLayout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.left_drawer_layout);
    navList.setAdapter(adapter);


    navList.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, final int pos,long id){
            //Change view according to numbers

            drawer.closeDrawer(linearLayout);
        }
    });

    //filter list view after search instantly
    searchBar.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence cs, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {
            // When user changed the Text
            MainActivity.this.adapter.getFilter().filter(cs);
        }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2,int arg3) {

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        }
    });

    //hide the keyboard after search on touch list view
    navList.setOnScrollListener(new AbsListView.OnScrollListener() {
        public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view, int scrollState) {
            //hide keyboard
            InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
            imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(navList.getWindowToken(), 0);
        }

        public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem, int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {
        }
    });

    navList.setEmptyView(findViewById(R.id.empty));

  }
}
```

The line:

```
adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>this,R.layout.list_item,R.id.element_name,elename);
```

assign the value of `final String[] elename` to a `textview` in my layout. So, is there any way to add one more `textview` and assign it the value of `final String[] nos` in the same line or without having to make a new class?.

Sorry if this is a dumb question but I am a beginner!

EDIT: Crash logcat

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.example.navigationdrawer.CustomAdapter.getView(CustomAdapter.java:34)
    at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:1592)
    at android.widget.ListView.makeAndAddView(ListView.java:1782)
    at android.widget.ListView.fillDown(ListView.java:705)
    at android.widget.ListView.fillFromTop(ListView.java:762)
    at android.widget.ListView.layoutChildren(ListView.java:1633)
    at android.widget.AbsListView.onLayout(AbsListView.java:1422)
    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:7175)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1254)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1130)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1047)
    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:7175)
    at android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout.onLayout(DrawerLayout.java:702)
    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:7175)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:338)
    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:7175)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:338)
    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:7175)
    at android.view.ViewRoot.performTraversals(ViewRoot.java:1146)
    at android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.java:1865)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3687)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:867)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:625)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

EDIT: MainActivity Crash

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.Chinmay.navigationdrawer.MainActivity$2.onTextChanged(MainActivity.java:66)
    at android.widget.TextView.sendOnTextChanged(TextView.java:6584)
    at android.widget.TextView.handleTextChanged(TextView.java:6631)
    at android.widget.TextView$ChangeWatcher.onTextChanged(TextView.java:6775)
    at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.sendTextChange(SpannableStringBuilder.java:889)
    at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.change(SpannableStringBuilder.java:352)
    at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.change(SpannableStringBuilder.java:269)
    at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.replace(SpannableStringBuilder.java:432)
    at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.replace(SpannableStringBuilder.java:409)
    at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.replace(SpannableStringBuilder.java:28)
    at android.view.inputmethod.BaseInputConnection.replaceText(BaseInputConnection.java:654)
    at android.view.inputmethod.BaseInputConnection.setComposingText(BaseInputConnection.java:415)
    at com.android.internal.view.IInputConnectionWrapper.executeMessage(IInputConnectionWrapper.java:328)
    at com.android.internal.view.IInputConnectionWrapper$MyHandler.handleMessage(IInputConnectionWrapper.java:79)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3687)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:867)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:625)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

New updated Mainactivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
final String[] elename ={"Hydrogen","Helium","Lithium","Beryllium","Boron","Carbon","Nitrogen","Oxygen","Fluorine","Neon","Sodium","Magnesium","Aluminium","Silicon","Phosphorous","Sulphur","Chlorine","Argon","Potassium","Calcium","Scandium","Titanium","Vanadium","Chromium","Manganese","Iron","Cobalt","Nickel","Copper","Zinc","Gallium","Germanium","Arsenic","Selenium","Bromine","Krypton","Rubidium","Strontium","Yttrium","Zirconium","Niobium","Molybdenum","Technetium","Ruthenium","Rhodium","Palladium","Silver","Cadmium","Indium","Tin","Antimony","Tellurium","Iodine","Xenon","Caesium","Barium","Lanthanum","Cerium","Praseodymium","Neodymium","Promethium","Samarium","Europium","Gadolinium","Terbium","Dysprosium","Holmium","Erbium","Thulium","Ytterbium","Lutetium","Hafnium","Tantalum","Tungsten","Rhenium","Osmium","Iridium","Platinum","Gold","Mercury","Thallium","Lead","Bismuth","Polonium","Astatine","Radon","Francium","Radium","Actinium","Thorium","Protactinium","Uranium","Neptunium","Plutonium","Americium","Curium","Berkelium","Californium","Einsteinium","Fermium","Mendelevium","Nobelium","Lawrencium","Rutherfordium","Dubnium","Seaborgium","Bohrium","Hassium","Meitnerium","Darmstadtium","Roentgenium","Copernicium","Ununtrium","Ununquadium","Ununpentium","Ununhexium","Ununseptium","Ununoctium"};
final String[] nos = {"1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","10","11","12","13","14","15","16","17","18","19","20","21","22","23","24","25","26","27","28","29","30","31","32","33","34","35","36","37","38","39","40","41","42","43","44","45","46","47","48","49","50","51","52","53","54","55","56","57","58","59","60","61","62","63","64","65","66","67","68","69","70","71","72","73","74","75","76","77","78","79","80","81","82","83","84","85","86","87","88","89","90","91","92","93","94","95","96","97","98","99","100","101","102","103","104","105","106","107","108","109","110","111","112","113","114","115","116","117","118"};
CustomAdapter cus;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    final EditText searchBar = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.searchbar);
    final DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout)findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    final ListView navList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.left_drawer);
    final LinearLayout linearLayout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.left_drawer_layout);
    CustomAdapter cus = new CustomAdapter(MainActivity.this,elename,nos);
    navList.setAdapter(cus);


    navList.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, final int pos,long id){
            //Change view according to numbers

            drawer.closeDrawer(linearLayout);
        }
    });

    //filter list view after search instantly
    searchBar.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence cs, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {
            // When user changed the Text
            MainActivity.this.cus.getFilter().filter(cs);
        }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2,int arg3) {

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        }
    });

    //hide the keyboard after search on touch list view
    navList.setOnScrollListener(new AbsListView.OnScrollListener() {
        public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view, int scrollState) {
            //hide keyboard
            InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
            imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(navList.getWindowToken(), 0);
        }

        public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem, int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {
        }
    });

    navList.setEmptyView(findViewById(R.id.empty));

}
}
```

Comment: yes you can http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16062569/how-to-construct-and-display-the-info-in-simple-list-item-2.

Comment: @Raghunandan can you please post the code with reference to my question so that it will be easier to understand as i have 118 values in my `elename` and `nos`.

Comment: pls read the docs and use the link as a reference. if you are asking for a complete code sorry i can't help

Comment: nope i am not asking for complete code sir, what I am asking is which method to override and where.

Comment: see the link posted override `getView`

Comment: but i don't have getview in my code!

Comment: ArrayAdapter has. see the docs. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html

Comment: Yup I will try! so should it be something like this:
`@Override
    public View getView(context, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, android.R.id.text1,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_2, android.R.layout.text2, navList`)  or should i inflate a view as given [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12400338/explanation-of-the-getview-method-of-an-arrayadapter)

Comment: let me know if you face difficulty then i will help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html

You can do as below picked from patrick's answer @
[How to construct and display the info in simple_list_item_2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16062569/how-to-construct-and-display-the-info-in-simple-list-item-2)

```
new ArrayAdapter (context, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_2, android.R.id.text1, list)
  {
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
      View view = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
      TextView text1 = (TextView) view.findViewById(android.R.id.text1);
      TextView text2 = (TextView) view.findViewById(android.R.id.text2);
      text1.setText(elename[positon]);
      text2.setText(nos[position]);
      return view;
    }
  });
```

Or use a CustomAdapter extending ArrayAdapter

```
  class CustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String>
  {
       String A[],B[];
       LayoutInfalter mInfalter;    
       public CustomAdapter(Context context, String[] A,String B[])
       {
          super(context,R.layout.customlayout,A);
          this.A = A;
          this.B = B;
          mInfalter = LayoutInfalter.from(context);
       }   
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
          ViewHolder holder;
          if(convertView==null)
          {
               convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.customlayout,parent,false);
               holder = new ViewHolder();
               holder.tv1 = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView1); 
               holder.tv2 = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView2);  
               convertView.setTag(holder); 
          }else{
                holder = (ViewHolder)convertVire.getTag();
          } 

                holder.tv1.setText(A[positon]);
                holder.tv2.setText(B[position]);
          return convertVIew;
    }
    static class ViewHolder
    {
        TextView tv1,tv2;
    }    
  }
```

Have a layout `customlayout.xml` with 2 textviews with id textView1 and textView 2 repectively.

Then

```
 CustomAdapter cus = new CustomAdapter(ActivityName.this,elename,nos);
 navList.setAdapter(cus);
```

Comment: @user3234390 where you have the previous adapter code. You need to read the docs

Comment: @user3234390 you still don't know where to place the code after seeing the edit

Comment: extremely sorry. had probs with net connection. I am trying it out right now!

Comment: @user3234390 so what happens now? works or not working??

Comment: just give me 2 mins. Will surely tell you the result!

Comment: Its force closing. Here's the stack trace:
`java.lang.NullPointerException`

Comment: @user3234390 indicate the line by looking at caused by part in logcat. also which method did you use the first or second?

Comment: I used the second method.

Comment: @user3234390 what is line 34 `CustomAdapter.java`

Comment: line 34 is `holder.tv1.setText(A[position]);`

Comment: @user3234390 do you have a layout called mylayout with 2 textviews with id textView1 and textView2?

Comment: I got my mistake sir!

Comment: @user3234390 that i thought was easy for oyu so i don't post the same. read my answer again. if you don't initialize you end up in NPE.

Comment: but now it crashed when i type something in the textview.

Comment: @user3234390 it will not. post the updated code and the stacktrace updated one and indicate the line of crash. There is nothing to type. listview is dynamic

Comment: The line indicated is this : `MainActivity.this.cus.getFilter().filter(cs);` It is in my mainactivity that will filter the lisview.

Comment: @user3234390 cus is null where is declared and initalized?. Make sure you declared before onCreate and initialize in onCrate

Comment: I will post my entire mainactivity. please check my updated question

Comment: @user3234390 do as suggested in my previous comment

Comment: i initalised it this way: 
`CustomAdapter cus = new CustomAdapter(MainActivity.this,elename,nos);` but its not working

Comment: @user3234390 delcare it outside onCreate and initialzie in onCreate

Comment: Oh i got it! but can u just help me one last time? the app doesn't force close but the search is not working properly! i type something and it shows wrong results!

Comment: @user3234390 accept this answer and start a new question with relevant details. too much commenting leading to a discussion

Comment: Ok sure. But please help me out with my new question.

Comment: please check my new question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21383747/listview-filtering-not-working-android