# Listview filtering not working - Android

Tags: android, android-listview, android-search

I am tying to implement search functionality in  my app. I am using a custom `ArrayAdapter<String>` for the `listview` as I have two `textViews` in a row. My app doesn't force close but the search is not working properly. It is not filtering the listview but when I type something that is not there in the listview, it shows the no item found page properly. What could be wrong? Here is the code. Please guide me to the correct path!

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
final String[] elename ={"Hydrogen","Helium","Lithium","Beryllium","Boron","Carbon","Nitrogen","Oxygen","Fluorine","Neon","Sodium","Magnesium","Aluminium","Silicon","Phosphorous","Sulphur","Chlorine","Argon","Potassium","Calcium","Scandium","Titanium","Vanadium","Chromium","Manganese","Iron","Cobalt","Nickel","Copper","Zinc","Gallium","Germanium","Arsenic","Selenium","Bromine","Krypton","Rubidium","Strontium","Yttrium","Zirconium","Niobium","Molybdenum","Technetium","Ruthenium","Rhodium","Palladium","Silver","Cadmium","Indium","Tin","Antimony","Tellurium","Iodine","Xenon","Caesium","Barium","Lanthanum","Cerium","Praseodymium","Neodymium","Promethium","Samarium","Europium","Gadolinium","Terbium","Dysprosium","Holmium","Erbium","Thulium","Ytterbium","Lutetium","Hafnium","Tantalum","Tungsten","Rhenium","Osmium","Iridium","Platinum","Gold","Mercury","Thallium","Lead","Bismuth","Polonium","Astatine","Radon","Francium","Radium","Actinium","Thorium","Protactinium","Uranium","Neptunium","Plutonium","Americium","Curium","Berkelium","Californium","Einsteinium","Fermium","Mendelevium","Nobelium","Lawrencium","Rutherfordium","Dubnium","Seaborgium","Bohrium","Hassium","Meitnerium","Darmstadtium","Roentgenium","Copernicium","Ununtrium","Ununquadium","Ununpentium","Ununhexium","Ununseptium","Ununoctium"};
final String[] nos = {"1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","10","11","12","13","14","15","16","17","18","19","20","21","22","23","24","25","26","27","28","29","30","31","32","33","34","35","36","37","38","39","40","41","42","43","44","45","46","47","48","49","50","51","52","53","54","55","56","57","58","59","60","61","62","63","64","65","66","67","68","69","70","71","72","73","74","75","76","77","78","79","80","81","82","83","84","85","86","87","88","89","90","91","92","93","94","95","96","97","98","99","100","101","102","103","104","105","106","107","108","109","110","111","112","113","114","115","116","117","118"};
CustomAdapter cus;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    final EditText searchBar = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.searchbar);
    final DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout)findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    final ListView navList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.left_drawer);
    final LinearLayout linearLayout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.left_drawer_layout);
    cus = new CustomAdapter(MainActivity.this,elename,nos);
    navList.setAdapter(cus);


    navList.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, final int pos,long id){
            //Change view according to numbers

            drawer.closeDrawer(linearLayout);
        }
    });

    //filter list view after search instantly
    searchBar.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence cs, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {
            // When user changed the Text
            MainActivity.this.cus.getFilter().filter(cs);
        }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2,int arg3) {

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        }
    });

    //hide the keyboard after search on touch list view
    navList.setOnScrollListener(new AbsListView.OnScrollListener() {
        public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view, int scrollState) {
            //hide keyboard
            InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
            imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(navList.getWindowToken(), 0);
        }

        public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem, int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {
        }
    });

    navList.setEmptyView(findViewById(R.id.empty));

}
}
```

**CustomAdapter.java**

```
class CustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String>
{
String A[],B[];
LayoutInflater mInflater;
public CustomAdapter(Context context, String[] A,String B[])
{
    super(context,R.layout.list_item,A);
    this.A = A;
    this.B = B;
    mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
}
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ViewHolder holder;
    if(convertView==null)
    {
        convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item,parent,false);
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.tv1 = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.element_name);
        holder.tv2 = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.element_nos);
        convertView.setTag(holder);
    }else{
        holder = (ViewHolder)convertView.getTag();
    }

    holder.tv1.setText(A[position]);
    holder.tv2.setText(B[position]);
    return convertView;
}
static class ViewHolder
{
    TextView tv1,tv2;
}
}
```

EDIT: App force closing after the implementation of interface.

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.Chinmay.navigationdrawer/com.Chinmay.navigationdrawer.MainActivity}: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.Chinmay.navigationdrawer.MainActivity
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1651)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1667)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:935)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3687)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:867)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:625)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
    Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.Chinmay.navigationdrawer.MainActivity
    at com.Chinmay.navigationdrawer.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:49)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1615)
```

Comment: Take a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14663725/list-view-filter-android/14663821#14663821) answer. It might help.

Comment: on what basis do you want the search to happen?

Comment: @Raghunndan the search will search the `String elename` and filter it instantly as i type!

Comment: @user3234390 sorry posted wrong link. check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13090046/how-to-implement-search-in-customlistview-based-on-class-item-of-pojo-class-in-a and i guess you are the user who was asking questions about navigation drawer.

Comment: if you have two Strings to show on each iten dont use String as a generic type for ArrayAdapter, use a class holding these two Steings

Answer (score 0):

Add this `cus.setSearchFilterItemListener(this);` before `navList.setAdapter(cus);`

**Update**

**Step 1**
Create an interface

```
public interface SearchFilterItemListener {

    public void setData(String[] myArray);
}
```

**Step 2**
Update your custom adapter class

```
class CustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {
    String A[], B[], origA[], origB[];
    LayoutInflater mInflater;

public CustomAdapter(Context context, String[] A,String B[]) {
    super(context, R.layout.list_item, A);
    this.A = A;
    this.B = B;
    this.origA = A;
    this.origB = B;
    mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
}

public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ViewHolder holder;
    if(convertView == null) {
        convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, parent, false);
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.tv1 = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.element_name);
        holder.tv2 = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.element_nos);
        convertView.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder)convertView.getTag();
    }

    holder.tv1.setText(A[position]);
    holder.tv2.setText(B[position]);
    return convertView;
}

static class ViewHolder {
    TextView tv1,tv2;
}

@Override
public Filter getFilter() {
    if (listFilter == null)
        listFilter = new TabFilter();
    return listFilter;
}

private class TabFilter extends Filter {

    @Override
    protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        FilterResults results = new FilterResults();
        // Filter Logic
        if (constraint == null || constraint.length() == 0) {
            // No filter, return all the list
            results.values = origA; //considering that you want to filter on the String[] A
            results.count = origA.size();
        } else {
            // We perform filtering operation
            String[] nList = new String[A.length];

            for (int counter = 0; counter < A.length; counter++) {
                if (A[counter].toUpperCase(Locale.US).startsWith(constraint.toString().toUpperCase(Locale.US)))
                    nList[counter] = A[counter];
            }
            results.values = nList;
            results.count = nList.length;
        }

        return results;
    }

    @Override
    protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        // Now we have to inform the adapter about the new filtered list
        if (results.count == 0)
            notifyDataSetInvalidated();
        else {
            A = (String[]) results.values;
            String[] newList = new String[A.length];
            newList = A.clone();

            notifyDataSetChanged();

            mSearchListener.setData(newList);
        }
    }
}

public String[] getSearchList() {
    return A;
}

public void setSearchFilterItemListener(SearchFilterItemListener mSearchFilterListener) {

    mSearchListener = mSearchFilterListener;
}
```

}

Comment: it shows error : `could not resolve method (cus.setSearchFilterItemListener(this))`

Comment: Check my updated answer!! Apologies for the inconvenience caused.

Comment: in which file should i put the interface? I am beginner so i don't know about them. please forgive me if its a dumb question sir!

Comment: its force closing after i implement your code sir. please have a look at my question!

Comment: I didn't get what is `mSearchListener` and `listFilter` and it shows couldn't resolve both the symbols. Also, the method `origA.size()` cannot be resolved. Please help!

Comment: Declare this in your adapter
`private SearchFilterItemListener mSearchListener;` and replace `origA.size()` with  `origA.length`.

Answer (score 0):

ok so this is your adapter:

```
class CustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Item> {
    LayoutInflater mInflater;
    public CustomAdapter(Context context) {
        super(context, 0);
        mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder holder;
        if(convertView == null) {
            convertView = mInflater.inflate(android.R.layout.simple_expandable_list_item_2, parent, false);
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.tv1 = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(android.R.id.text1);
            holder.tv2 = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(android.R.id.text2);
            convertView.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder)convertView.getTag();
        }

        Item item = getItem(position);
        holder.tv1.setText(item.text1);
        holder.tv2.setText(item.text2);
        return convertView;
    }
}
```

now you have Item class holding two Strings:

```
class Item {
    String text1;
    String text2;
    Item(String t1, String t2) {
        text1 = t1;
        text2 = t2;
    }
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return text1;
    }
}
```

and the ViewHolder:

```
class ViewHolder {
    TextView tv1, tv2;
}
```

now test it in onCreate (try to press any letter, "p" for example to filter out thos items starting with "p":

```
CustomAdapter adapter = new CustomAdapter(this);
for (int i = 0; i < elename.length; i++) {
    adapter.add(new Item(elename[i], nos[i]));
}
lv = new ListView(this);
lv.setTextFilterEnabled(true);
lv.setAdapter(adapter);
setContentView(lv);
```

Comment: some problem with the adapter.add method.

Comment: it says java.lang.string in arrayadapter cannot be applied and for the line `Item item = getItem(position);` it says incompatible types.

Comment: I'm sorry there is no problem in onCreate but for the line `Item item = getItem(position);` it says incompatible types

Comment: in the lines : `holder.tv1.setText(item.text1);
        holder.tv2.setText(item.text2);` is item = Item? and when I change that, it says that cannot resolve method and symbol.

Comment: Also is Item = ClipData.Item? because it says incompatible types :
 Required :com.Chinmay.navigationdrawer.CustomAdapter.Item
 Found : android.Content.ClipData.Item.

Comment: I'll will expain the scenario clearly: the line `Item item = getItem(position);` gives the error incompatible types. When I change it to `ClipData.Item item = getItem(position);` the two lines below it
give the error cannot resolve mothod and cannot resolve symbol. Please help me out.

Comment: exactly! I don't know what is clipdata! I got it from the suggestions.
The line `class CustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Item>` itself shows the following error : cannot find class symbol even after adding the class Item.

Comment: again: add Item class i posted in the **answer**

Comment: please post final code so that It will be easier ! and the problem persists!